# Import Data from Excel to R, More columns than column names

Tags: r, excel

I can not import the excel data to R for some reason even though I use the most common approach that is shown in every video:

```
read.csv(file.choose(), header = TRUE)
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote =       quote,  : 
more columns than column names
```

I don't understand the statement 'more columns than column names' as the excel table is very small and easy.

Comment: if you trying to read a .xlsx file with `read.csv()` you are gonna have a bad time. look at `xlsx::read.xlsx()`

Comment: Another option to directly read Excel files is using `readxl::read_excel`.